# VBA code that concatenates "unique" values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a VBA code that will take values from a selection and concatenate the cell values with a line seperator. I also wish to not include and duplicates.

Ex. as follows:

Say I have a data set like the below. I would like to type =ConcatenateUnique(A1:B2,",") and have it return One,Two,Three

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| One | Two |
| Three | One |

I tried the below, although I'm aware if it did work it would only return Two,Three

```
Function CONCATENATEUNIQUE(Ref As Range, Separator As String) As String
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Result As String
For Each Cell In Ref
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Ref, Cell.Value) <= 1 Then
Result = Result & Cell.Value & Separator
End If
Next Cell
CONCATENATEMULTIPLE = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this type of task a Scripting Dictionary is useful (but note this won't work on a Mac):

```vb
Function UniqueList(rng As Range, Optional sep As String = ",")
    Dim arr, r As Long, c As Long, v, dict As Object
    If rng.Count = 1 Then 'handle single-cell case
        UniqueList = rng.Value
        Exit Function
    End If
    arr = rng.Value 'get values into an array
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
        v = arr(r, c)
        If Not IsError(v) Then
            If Len(v) > 0 Then dict(v) = True
        End If
    Next c
    Next r
    UniqueList = Join(Application.Transpose( _
                       Application.Transpose(dict.Keys)), sep)
End Function
```

Comment: Is there a reason why not just `UniqueList = Join(dict.Keys, sep)` ?

Comment: That worked perfectly. I got lost on the two "for" statements but will do some googling to understand it better.

Comment: The two For loops are for looping over the "rows" and "columns" of the 2-D array `arr`.  When you read a range into an array using `.Value` it's always a two-dimensional array with the same size as the source range (assuming there's >1 cell being read).   Reading to an array and then looping over the array is much faster than reading cell-by-cell from the worksheet.